APIM overrides the value of server url to wrong link
I am using APIM v2 tier, when i first created the instance I got the default api gateway and when i import an api it takes that default uri in the servers url section like following:
"servers": [{
        "url": "https://test-apim.azure-api.net/staging/data-product/base"
    }],

Then i have created a custom domain with the name apis.mydomain.de , then i deleted that custom domain(apis.mydomain.de) but unfortunately now whenever i create a new api i got the server url like this:
"servers": [{
        "url": "https://apis.mydomain.de/staging/data-product/base"
     }],

and when I got to settings to verify the Base URL I actually find it pointing to the default gateway(which is correct); but when i open the developer portal or open the api specification as json i found it pointing on the deleted custom domain
I tried to change the server url diectly on the json specification, when i save it appears saved but all my changes got discarded and remains with the wrong server url.
here i attach a screenshot of the custom domain blade

A solution or an explanation for this would really help.

Did you publish the site after making the changes?

hello, thank you for replying. yes i did many times and waited along

Can you share the screenshot of the custom domain blade?

sure, i have added it to the question. as i told you i kept only the default and deleted my custom

Default SSL binding property should be ticked for you. See this

thats true, i can not see it. why is that?

Which plan are you on?

am on standard v2 (the new tier)

What are you seeing the overview blade for developer portal and gateway URL? What type of custom domain have you created gateway or developer portal?

Can you try to create a fresh instance

To access the default gateway after deleting the custom domain, verify the following-

Make sure, the APIM instance is in Online state post deletion.
Developer plan or higher comes with Default SSL binding option but not standard plan. If the custom domain deleted successfully then by default it will point to the default gateway.
Publish the Developer portal site after making the changes in the APIM instance.
Try to create a new API and check the base URL for the same.
You can also validate the gateway URL and Developer Portal in Overview blade.


If you are still getting the deleted custom domain endpoints then I would suggest you to create a fresh instance.

So, after opening a ticket to Microsoft support, it appreared to be an issue from their side happening in the v2 tiers.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
